# How to show the result that depends on the condition?

Tags: javascript

Please help me figure it out.
The task is simple, but for some reason I can not solve it.
How to show the result that depends on the condition?

```js
let numLevel = 25;
for (i = numLevel; i >= 30; i++) {
  if (28 < numLevel <= 30) {
    console.log('result 1');
  }
  if (21 < numLevel < 28) {
    console.log('result 2');
  }
  if (15 < numLevel < 21) {
    console.log('result 3');
  }
  if (10 < numLevel < 15) {
    console.log('result 4');
  }
  if (7 < numLevel < 10) {
    console.log('result 5');
  }
  if (0 <= numLevel < 7) {
    console.log('result 6');
  } else {
    console.log('Nan')
  }
}
```

or

```js
let numLevel = 25;

if (28 < numLevel <= 30) {
  console.log('result 1');
}
if (21 < numLevel < 28) {
  console.log('result 2');
}
if (15 < numLevel < 21) {
  console.log('result 3');
}
if (10 < numLevel < 15) {
  console.log('result 4');
}
if (7 < numLevel < 10) {
  console.log('result 5');
}
if (0 <= numLevel < 7) {
  console.log('result 6');
} else {
  console.log('Nan')
}
```

Should appear "result 2"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When the `for` loop starts, `i` is set to `25`. The loop runs while `i` is `>= 30` but this never happens.

Comment: The `for` loop is not even needed. The code inside it does not depend on the loop variable `i`. Unless you want to execute the same code several times but it does not make any sense here.

Comment: Also use console.log instead of alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- you have to use `&&` to concatenate conditions
- the task is not logically defined:

  - `IF` you want to list all ranges that `numLevel` is included?

    - what if ranges intersect? e.g. share at least one common point; what is the expected output in this case?
  - `OR` you want to see only first range that includes `numLevel`?

    - you have to use `else if` for exhaustiveness

To see the first range that includes `numLevel = 25`

```
let numLevel = 25;

if (28 < numLevel && numLevel <= 30) {
    alert('result 1');
} else if (21 < numLevel  && numLevel < 28) {
    alert('result 2');
} else if (15 < numLevel && numLevel < 21) {
    alert('result 3');
} else if (10 < numLevel && numLevel < 15) {
    alert('result 4');
} else if (7 < numLevel && numLevel < 10) {
    alert('result 5');
} else if (0 <= numLevel && numLevel < 7) {
    alert('result 6');
} else {
   alert('Nan')
}
```

to see all ranges that include `numLevel = 25`:

```
let numLevel = 25;

if (28 < numLevel && numLevel <= 30) {
    alert('numLevel is in (28;30] : result 1');
}

if (21 < numLevel  && numLevel < 28) {
    alert('numLevel is in (21;28) : result 2');
}

if (15 < numLevel && numLevel < 21) {
    alert('numLevel is in (15;21) : result 3');
}

if (10 < numLevel && numLevel < 15) {
    alert('numLevel is in (10;15) : result 4');
}

if (7 < numLevel && numLevel < 10) {
    alert('numLevel is in (7;10) : result 5');
}

if (0 <= numLevel && numLevel < 7) {
    alert('numLevel is in [0;7): result 6');
}
```

**P.S.** advice - try to use [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) and `console.log` for a better usability during your dev journey. This one is a good basic Node install and usage YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsH-fizHkcY)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 different checks. also, check if isNaN

```js
let numLevel = 25;

if (28 < numLevel && numLevel <= 30) {
  alert('result 1');
}
if (21 < numLevel && numLevel < 28) {
  alert('result 2');
}
if (15 < numLevel && numLevel < 21) {
  alert('result 3');
}
if (10 < numLevel && numLevel < 15) {
  alert('result 4');
}
if (7 < numLevel && numLevel < 10) {
  alert('result 5');
}
if (0 <= numLevel && numLevel < 7) {
  alert('result 6');
} else if (isNaN(numLevel)) {
  alert('Nan');
}
```